# Get string between two strings?

Tags: ruby, xml, string

I have a string:

```
<products type="array">
<product><brand>Rho2</brand>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-11-03T21:29:46Z</created-at><id type="integer">78013</id><name>Test2</name>
<price nil="true"/>
<quantity nil="true"/>
<sku nil="true"/>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-11-03T21:29:46Z</updated-at>
</product>
<product>
<brand>Apple</brand>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-10-26T21:26:59Z</created-at>
<id type="integer">77678</id>
<name>iPhone</name>
<price>$199.99</price>
<quantity>5</quantity>
<sku>1234</sku>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-10-26T21:27:00Z</updated-at>
</product>
```

I want to get the text between `<brand>` and `</brand>`.

I am trying to parse this XML, collecting data between tags.

Comment: you wrote "is get text between and ." - maybe you miss tag names?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Is there some reason you can't just parse the XML using one of any number of libraries, and then retrieve your data sensibly?

Comment: REXML or XmlSimple should do the trick. Yeah, the xml can be in a string, it will still parse. There are a lot more libraries around. Here a [working example](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: @muffista: Just help me in getting the desired string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use any XML parser available in you platform. Then you can use simple XPath expression:

```
//brand
```

It selects all `brand` elements in document.

Answer (score 1):

[XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) should be easy.

```
 require 'xmlsimple'
 products = XmlSimple.xml_in('<YOUR WHOLE XML>', { 'KeyAttr' => 'product' })
```

Answer (score 0):

The defacto standard for parsing XML and HTML in Ruby is [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) these days:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<products type="array">
  <product>
    <brand>Rho2</brand>
    <created-at type="datetime">2011-11-03T21:29:46Z</created-at>
  </product>
  <product>
    <brand>Apple</brand>
    <created-at type="datetime">2011-10-26T21:26:59Z</created-at>
  </product>  
</products>
EOT

puts doc.search('brand').map(&:text)
```

Which outputs:

```
Rho2
Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStringBetween(str , fromStr , toStr){
  var fromStrIndex = str.indexOf(fromStr) == -1 ? 0 : str.indexOf(fromStr) + fromStr.length;
  var toStrIndex = str.slice(fromStrIndex).indexOf(toStr) == -1 ? str.length-1 : str.slice(fromStrIndex).indexOf(toStr) + fromStrIndex;
  var strBtween = str.substring(fromStrIndex,toStrIndex);
  return strBtween;
}
```